# SQL Error: Missing Right Parenthesis in Line 1 ORA-00907

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, create-table

I've checked other similar questions. about repeating commas, error in commands but cant find any in my error. I've also searched examples of create tables to compare with mine, but fail to find any difference :(.

Below is the CREATE table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVER(L# VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
                       , DNAME VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL
                       , STATUS  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                       , NRIC VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
                       , PRIMARY KEY(L#)
                       , CANDIDATE KEY(NRIC)
      );
```

Anyone can help me point out that i can't see or missing something,thanks (:

Comment: [Oracle Corporation strongly discourages you from using $ and #.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements9a.htm)

Comment: Even if # wasn't illegal, using L# as a name is really obscure.  Use clear explicit names or your code will become unmaintainable.

Comment: While `#` is discouraged, that's not the issue here. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify `CANDIDATE KEY` like that in Oracle. The right way is to create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on your Candidate Key(s).

Like so.

#### Here's a working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b392d/1

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVER(
    L# VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    DNAME VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL, 
    STATUS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    NRIC VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY(L#),
    CONSTRAINT UK_NRIC UNIQUE (NRIC)
);
```

Comment: It's a good idea to name constraints, including (especially) primary keys.  Managing them and their associated indexes is a major pain when they have system-generated names.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00907 pretty much always indicates a syntax error.  It happens when the parser finds a word which is not a key word in a position where it is expecting either a keyword or a right-hand bracket to close the current statement (hence `Missing Right Parenthesis`).  Although sometime it can just be that we have an unmatched left-hand bracket: a decent text editor can help trace that.

In your case the intruding word is `CANDIDATE`.  Syntax errors can be tricky for beginners.  I recommend you familarise yourself with the Oracle documentation:it is online, complete and free, and has quite a lot of examples.  [Check it out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) .  The [list of reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621) could have helped you, because `CANDIDATE` is not on it, which is a big clue.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use odd characters in a name, wrap it in square brackets. []